# Ruby on rails "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run the following code on a form I get the following error message:

> ```
> undefined method `store_ID' for # <Store:0x007f98ec2a1d68>
> ```

I checked the model, controller, and schema but the store_ID is consistent with the other working parameters. How do I "define" it first?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@store) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence
        if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :location, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :branch_manager, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :store_ID, required: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here are my `schema.rb`

```
create_table "stores", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t| 
    t.string "location" 
    t.string "branch_manager" 
    t.integer "store_ID" 
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false 
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false 
end
```

Comment: What's your db schema? Shouldn't it be `store_id`?

Comment: I added the ID field after I generated everything so i don't know if that makes a difference. Here's my schema related to stores:
      create_table "stores", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "location"
    t.string "branch_manager"
    t.integer "store_ID"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Comment: Restart the server

Comment: I would recommend making it `store_id` for consistency. Having "random" cappital letters in a DB column/method name will most likely cause confusion down the line. But as @fool-dev says, you probably just haven't restarted the server.

Comment: You also may wish to add a `null: false` database constraint for `store_id`, and maybe a unique index too. Depends on the business logic in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not run the migrations according to what you say

"I added the ID field after generating everything, so I do not know if that makes the difference"

With this you should solve:

```
rails db:migrate
```